# How to block a port from all traffic on all interfaces in Mac OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

Tags: macos, firewall, pf

I need to block port `27017` to do some testing but I can’t seem to figure out how to do it in Mac OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite). I know that sometime ago they moved from `iptables` to [`pf`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/pf.conf.5.html) tables, but the information I can find specifically for blocking a port (in and out) is sparse.

Specifically I need some help with the following:

- How do I block all TCP traffic (in and out) on port `27017` on all interfaces?
- Where do I put this blocking directive? I'm assuming there is a config file.
- Once I’ve placed the blocking line, how do I restart/reload the firewall?

***Edit***

From what [`pf`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/pf.conf.5.html) documentation I can grok this is what I have so far:

```
anchor "mongo" {
    block drop quick on any proto tcp from any to any to port 27107
}
```

I interpret this as `block` and `drop` connections quickly on `any` interface using the `tcp` protocol for connections going from `any` host to `any` server on port `27017`.